# Importing Data in R

Tags: r, csv, import, error-handling

I want to import data into R but I am getting a few errors. I download my ".CSV" file to my computer and specify the file path like this `setwd("C:/Users/intellipaat/Desktop/BLOG/files")` and then I am writing `read.data <- read.csv("file1.csv")`, but the console returns an error like this.

> "read.data<-read.csv(file1.csv)
> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
> 'file1.csv' object not found

What should I do for this? I tried the internet link route, but again I encountered a problem.

I wrote like this:

```
install.packages("XML")
install.packages("RCurl")
```

to load the packages, run the following command:

```
library("XML")
library("RCurl")

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ease_of_doing_business_index#Ranking"
tabs <- getURL(url)
```

and the console wrote me this error;

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :
> error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

I would be glad if you help me in this regard...

Comment: what are you trying to do? Are you trying to read files from disk or you are trying to read a table from wikipedia. The file "file1.csv" is not present at your current working directory that is what error is telling you, it can be due to non availibility of file or names(case sensitive) are different what you have mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ease of Doing Business rankings table on Wikipedia is an HTML table, not a comma separated values file.

Loading the HTML table into an R data frame can be handled in a relatively straightforward manner with the `rvest` package. Instead of downloading the HTML file we can read it directly into R with `read_html()`, and then use `html_table()` to extract the tabular data into a data frame.

```
library(rvest)
wiki_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ease_of_doing_business_index#Ranking"

aPage <- read_html(wiki_url)
aTable <- html_table(aPage)[[2]] # second node is table of rankings
head(aTable)
```

...and the first few rows of output:

```
> head(aTable)
  Classification  Jurisdiction 2020 2019 2018 2017 2016 2015 2014 2013 2012
1      Very Easy   New Zealand    1    1    1    1    2    2    3    3    3
2      Very Easy     Singapore    2    2    2    2    1    1    1    1    1
3      Very Easy     Hong Kong    3    4    5    4    5    3    2    2    2
4      Very Easy       Denmark    4    3    3    3    3    4    5    5    5
5      Very Easy   South Korea    5    5    4    5    4    5    7    8    8
6      Very Easy United States    6    8    6    8    7    7    4    4    4
  2011 2010 2009 2008 2007 2006
1    3    2    2    2    2    1
2    1    1    1    1    1    2
3    2    3    4    4    5    7
4    6    6    5    5    7    8
5   16   19   23   30   23   27
6    5    4    3    3    3    3
>
```

Next, we confirm that the last countries were read correctly: Libya, Yemen, Venezuela, Eritrea, and Somalia.

```
> tail(aTable,n=5)
    Classification Jurisdiction 2020 2019 2018 2017 2016 2015 2014 2013 2012
186  Below Average        Libya  186  186  185  188  188  188  187  N/A  N/A
187  Below Average        Yemen  187  187  186  179  170  137  133  118   99
188  Below Average    Venezuela  188  188  188  187  186  182  181  180  177
189  Below Average      Eritrea  189  189  189  189  189  189  184  182  180
190  Below Average      Somalia  190  190  190  190  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A
    2011 2010 2009 2008 2007 2006
186  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A
187  105   99   98  113   98   90
188  172  177  174  172  164  120
189  180  175  173  171  170  137
190  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A
```

Finally, we use `tidyr` and `dplyr` to convert the data to narrow format tidy data for subsequent analysis.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
aTable %>% 
     # convert years 2017 - 2020 to character because pivot_longer() 
     # requires all columns to be of same data type
     mutate_at(3:6,as.character) %>% 
     pivot_longer(-c(Classification,Jurisdiction),
                  names_to="Year",values_to="Rank") %>%
     # convert Rank and Year to numeric values (introducing NA values)
     mutate_at(c("Rank","Year"),as.numeric) -> rankings
head(rankings)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(rankings)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Classification Jurisdiction  Year  Rank
  <chr>          <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
1 Very Easy      New Zealand   2020     1
2 Very Easy      New Zealand   2019     1
3 Very Easy      New Zealand   2018     1
4 Very Easy      New Zealand   2017     1
5 Very Easy      New Zealand   2016     2
6 Very Easy      New Zealand   2015     2
>
```